# How do I add to "system software sources"?

Tags: 12.04, acer, fluendo

While trying to install fluendo on my Acer C720 running 12.04, I was told to add this to my system software sources:

deb https://mjcohen:1J7knSnNsrDwh7pTGC88@private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/fluendo-dvd/ubuntu precise main

How do I do this?

This is on an Acer C720 running 12.04.

Comment: Eeek! That looks like a real password. Replace it, immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](http://askubuntu.com/q/4983/187281)

Answer (score 2):

Start **Ubuntu Software Center**.

From the top menu select the **Edit** menu item and then the **Software Sources...** menu item.

This brings up a dialog box:

[image: Ubuntu Software Center Software Sources dialog box]

Select the **Other Software** tab.

On the Other Software tab dialog, click the **Add...** button

A dialog box will come up:
[image: Software Sources add Apt line dialog box]

Copy the "deb ... precise main" line into the Edit box in the dialog and click the **Add Source** button.